# Can the expss package process multiple answer questions with weighted data?

Tags: r, weighted, multiple-choice, expss

Can the expss package solve the question asked in this link?, it's about multiple response question with a weighting variable in the dataset

[How to use the R survey package to analyze multiple response questions in a weighted sample?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38675151/how-to-use-the-r-survey-package-to-analyze-multiple-response-questions-in-a-weig)

Let's suppose we have this dataset:

```
demo <- tribble(
~dummy1, ~dummy2, ~dummy3, ~survey_weight,
      1,       0,       0,          1.5,
      1,       1,       0,          1.5,
      1,       1,       1,           .5,
      0,       1,       1,          1.5,
      1,       1,       1,           .5,
      0,       0,       1,           .5,
)
```

I need to calculate the percentage based on total respondents who answered the question, and not on total responses

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is quite easy:

```
library(expss)
demo = text_to_columns("
    dummy1 dummy2 dummy3 survey_weight
    1        0        0           1.5
    1        1        0           1.5
    1        1        1            .5
    0        1        1           1.5
    1        1        1            .5
    0        0        1            .5
")


demo %>% 
    tab_cells(mdset(dummy1 %to% dummy3)) %>%  # 'mdset' designate that with have multiple dichotomy set
    tab_weight(survey_weight) %>% # weight
    tab_stat_cpct() %>% # statistic
    tab_pivot() 

# |              | #Total |
# | ------------ | ------ |
# |       dummy1 |   66.7 |
# |       dummy2 |   66.7 |
# |       dummy3 |   50.0 |
# | #Total cases |    6.0 |

# shorter notation with the same result
calc_cro_cpct(demo, mdset(dummy1 %to% dummy3), weight = survey_weight)
```

But note that `expss` use simple frequency weights in the SPSS style while 'survey' package can provide more accurate weighting schemes.